# How do I remove songs from the cloud

Tags: itunes

I have removed my son's death metal junk from my library but the devices still pick it up from the cloud.  How do I delete songs from the cloud if they no longer appear in the host ITunes library?  I have deleted the unwanted songs from the host PC which should have removed them from iTunes Match but when I synch my iPad mini to iTunes Match the files still appear and can be played on the iPad when I have access to the cloud thru WiFi.   The songs are gone from the host PC but apparently are still in accessible to my other devices thru iTunes Match.

Comment: Do you use iTunes Match, or do you sync music from your computer to your iDevice? Would you be willing to edit your question with a few more details such as the device(s) that still have the songs, how they got there in the first place, etc.

Comment: Use iTunes Match with the original songs on a PC.  I originally set up the iTunes Match with my son's old files still on the PC. I have since, deleted them but when I load to my iPad (thru Wifi connection) the old deleted files appear in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the item and select delete.    The popup will look like this:

[image]

make sure to click the *Also delee this song from iCloud box.

must be on Computer with Itunes Match enabled.

Check http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4915?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US